# Error occurs and app getting crash in open the fragment from one click button

Tags: java, android

I made the eCommerce website and i got the error at the time of purchasing because when i buy now the item than the payment integration work but its getting error. So, what is the solution of that if i click on the button and its open fragment.

ItemDetails.java (This is the code of buy now and here i implement some fragment code also but its not work properly)

```
public class ItemDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int imagePosition;
    String stringImageUri;
    public static int notificationCountCart = 0;
    TextView textViewshare, textViewmap;
    private Fragment fragment;




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        //Show cart layout based on items
        return true;
    }




        @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Get the notifications MenuItem and
        // its LayerDrawable (layer-list)
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
        NotificationCountSetClass.setAddToCart(ItemDetailsActivity.this, item, notificationCountCart);
        // force the ActionBar to relayout its MenuItems.
        // onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) will be called again.
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {

            startActivity(new Intent(ItemDetailsActivity.this, SearchResultActivity.class));
            return true;
        }else if (id == R.id.action_cart) {

           /* NotificationCountSetClass.setAddToCart(MainActivity.this, item, notificationCount);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();*/
            startActivity(new Intent(ItemDetailsActivity.this, CartListActivity.class));

           /* notificationCount=0;//clear notification count
            invalidateOptionsMenu();*/
            return true;
        }else {
            startActivity(new Intent(ItemDetailsActivity.this, EmptyActivity.class));

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_details);
        SimpleDraweeView mImageView = (SimpleDraweeView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
        TextView textViewAddToCart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_action_bottom1);
        TextView textViewBuyNow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_action_bottom2);
        textViewshare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_action1);
        textViewmap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_action3);
        TextView textViewBuyNowwithpayment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_action_bottom2);

        //Getting image uri from previous screen
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            stringImageUri = getIntent().getStringExtra(ImageListFragment.STRING_IMAGE_URI);
            imagePosition = getIntent().getIntExtra(ImageListFragment.STRING_IMAGE_URI,0);
        }

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(stringImageUri);
        mImageView.setImageURI(uri);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ItemDetailsActivity.this, ViewPagerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", imagePosition);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        textViewAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    ImageUrlUtils imageUrlUtils = new ImageUrlUtils();
                    imageUrlUtils.addCartListImageUri(stringImageUri);
                    Toast.makeText(ItemDetailsActivity.this, "Item added to cart.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    MainActivity.notificationCountCart++;
                    NotificationCountSetClass.setNotifyCount(MainActivity.notificationCountCart);




            }
        });


        textViewBuyNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImageUrlUtils imageUrlUtils = new ImageUrlUtils();
                imageUrlUtils.addCartListImageUri(stringImageUri);
                MainActivity.notificationCountCart++;
                NotificationCountSetClass.setNotifyCount(MainActivity.notificationCountCart);
                startActivity(new Intent(ItemDetailsActivity.this, CartListActivity.class));


            }
        });
//         payment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//             @Override
//             public void onClick(View v) {
//                 Intent i = new Intent(ItemDetailsActivity.this, PayPalCheckoutActivity.class);
//                 startActivity(i);
//             }
//         });

        textViewBuyNowwithpayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Fragment fragment = new PayPalCheckoutActivity();
//                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
//                transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // this will manage backstack
//                transaction.commit();

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                PayPalCheckoutActivity fragment = new PayPalCheckoutActivity();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
            }
        });
```

PaypalActivity.java (This is the java file where the payment integration will be start but my app getting crash after click on the buy now button )

```
public class PayPalCheckoutActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView textMessage = null;
    private CitrusClient citrusClient = null;
    private Button btnSignout = null;
    private Button btnUserManagement = null;
    private Button btnWalletPayment = null;
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn = false;

    public PayPalCheckoutActivity() {
    }

    public static PayPalCheckoutActivity newInstance() {
        return new PayPalCheckoutActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ui, container, false);
        textMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message);

        btnUserManagement = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_user_management);
        btnWalletPayment = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_user_wallet);
        btnSignout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        btnSignout.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        citrusClient = CitrusClient.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        citrusClient.signOut(new Callback<CitrusResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(CitrusResponse citrusResponse) {
                ((UIActivity) getActivity()).showSnackBar(citrusResponse.getMessage());

                textMessage.setText("Please Sign In or Sign Up the user.");
                btnSignout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void error(CitrusError error) {
                ((UIActivity) getActivity()).showSnackBar(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkUserLogin();
    }

    void checkUserLogin() {
        citrusClient.isUserSignedIn(new Callback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Boolean isUserLoggedIn) {
                PayPalCheckoutActivity.this.isUserLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn;
                if (isUserLoggedIn) {
                    citrusClient.getProfileInfo(new Callback<CitrusUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(CitrusUser citrusUser) {
                            textMessage.setText("Welcome " + citrusUser.getEmailId());
                            btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnSignout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void error(CitrusError error) {
                            textMessage.setText("Welcome Back");
                            btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnSignout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    textMessage.setText("Please Sign In or Sign Up the user.");
                    btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnSignout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void error(CitrusError error) {
                textMessage.setText(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.allandroidprojects.ecomsample, PID: 6112
         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0143 (com.allandroidprojects.ecomsample:id/fragment_container) for fragment PayPalCheckoutActivity{a633c04 #0 id=0x7f0e0143}
```

fragment_ui.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/citrus_activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/citrus_activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/citrus_activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/citrus_activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:text="Please Sign In or Sign Up the user." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_user_management"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:onClick="onUserManagementClicked"
        android:text="User Management" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_user_wallet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:onClick="onWalletPaymentClicked"
        android:text="Wallet Payment"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:text="Logout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_item_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_item_details"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="com.codeexpertise.eshop.product.ItemDetailsActivity">


    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="9.5"
              android:scrollbars="none"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   android:id="@+id/image1"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="200.0dp"
                                                   fresco:placeholderImage="@color/stay_color" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="Denim Shirt"
                          android:textSize="16dp"
                          android:textColor="@color/gen_black"/>
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                          android:text="Rs. 1,979"
                          android:textSize="20dp"
                          android:textColor="@color/gen_black"
                          />
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="FREE Delivery"
                          android:textSize="12dp"
                          android:layout_marginTop="4dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/text_ratings"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:background="@color/green_light"
                          android:paddingTop="2dp"
                          android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                          android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                          android:paddingRight="6dp"
                          android:text="4.3 *"
                          android:textSize="12dp"
                          android:textColor="@color/gen_white"
                          android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView android:id="@+id/text_ratings_reviews"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                          android:text="50 ratings \u0026 15 reviews"
                          android:textSize="12dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>/
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/view_width_small"
              android:background="@color/grey_light"
              android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_action1"
                          android:layout_width="0dp"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:gravity="center"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:weightSum="2">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_18dp"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/text_action1"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                          android:text="Share"
                     android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                          android:textSize="12dp"
                          android:textColor="@color/gen_black"
                          android:gravity="left"
                    android:actionProviderClass=
                        "android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View android:layout_width="@dimen/view_width_small"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="@color/grey_light"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_action2"
                          android:layout_width="0dp"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:gravity="center"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:weightSum="2">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/ic_filter_none_black_18dp"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/text_action2"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                          android:text="Similar"
                          android:textSize="12dp"
                          android:textColor="@color/gen_black"
                          android:gravity="left"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View android:layout_width="@dimen/view_width_small"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:background="@color/grey_light"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_action3"
                          android:layout_width="0dp"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:gravity="center"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:weightSum="2">
                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_18dp"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/text_action3"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="1"
                          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                          android:text="Store Locator"
                          android:textSize="12dp"
                          android:textColor="@color/gen_black"
                          android:gravity="left"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/view_width_small"
              android:background="@color/grey_light"
              android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="Details"
                      android:textSize="16dp"
                      android:textColor="@color/gen_black"/>
            <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                      android:text="\u2022 Regular fit, full sleeve"
                      android:textSize="12dp"
                      android:textColor="@color/gen_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="\u2022 Fabric: Cotton"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gen_black"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="\u2022 Pattern: printed"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gen_black"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        android:background="@color/gen_black">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_action_bottom1"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="@color/gen_white"
                  android:text="ADD TO CART"
                  android:textSize="14dp"
                  android:textColor="@color/gen_black"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_action_bottom2"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#4dc3ff"
                  android:text="BUY NOW"
                  android:textSize="14dp"
                  android:textColor="@color/gen_white"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your `activity_item_details.xml` alse here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try replace a `Framelayout` with id is `fragment_container`

when you try to replace/add fragment without use `FrameLayout` that time you should use `android.R.id.content`,

So Please replace you code like.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                PayPalCheckoutActivity fragment = new PayPalCheckoutActivity();
                fm.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,fragment).commit();
```

**or**

If you use `Framelayout` Once check your id `R.id.fragment_container` is Correct.

Comment: How its work ? if i use linear layout rather than framelayout.

Comment: I added it Please check it now @Raja

Comment: I checked your code, so you just use `android.R.id.content` instead of  `R.id.fragment_container` It will work.

Comment: Now its showing me this error                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.citrus.sdk.network.e.d()' on a null object reference

Comment: `CitrusClient.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());` here just give `CitrusClient.getInstance(getActivity());`

Comment: not working sorry. Error :-    at com.codeexpertise.eshop.startup.PayPalCheckoutActivity.checkUserLogin(PayPalCheckoutActivity.java:84)
                                                                                       at com.codeexpertise.eshop.startup.PayPalCheckoutActivity.onResume(PayPalCheckoutActivity.java:80)

Comment: Your Fragment has been replaced then show this error Right?

Comment: Your are asking the Question for ** No view found for id 0x7f0e0143**, Already given a solution, Please check your code if any other issuse., And Approve the answer because others can find the solution in easy.

Comment: thanks for helping me. let me check the other error problem. if u give me your mail id than pls provide me. i can't chat here because i dont have a 20 rep

Answer (score 0):

yes, you got this error. Take a look at this:

`fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();`

This line of code means that you will replace the `fragment` into a `viewgroup` with id: `R.id.fragment_container`. However, I do not see this id in your `activity` (the id is in your `fragment` instead).

To solve it, just move the id to your `activity_item_detail`.